# Firebase App Distribution app is linking to Google Play - App not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution, android-app-bundle

We have connected the play console from the firebase app distribution but still, it is saying No apps are linked. We have the project in play console with the same package name which is currently in an internal testing state. Not sure what is missing? I would be grateful if anybody has any insights on this.

Comment: We have same issue. Did you find what is the problem? I tripple checked AndroidManifest, build.gradle and google-services.json and package name is correct. I even downloaded google-services from Friebase directly.

Comment: @c0dehunter Yes! The problem was we had 2 projects in firebase one for production and one for QA and somebody connected firebase and play console in both it seems it doesn't work for both, We unliked from one and we were able to link it to the other. I hope this helps you.