# Trying to connect Google Play app to Firebase, but get "No matching Play apps found"

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I want to connect app from Google Play to Firebase, but it's saying

> No matching Play apps found. Please check Play Console to make sure
> you have access to an app with the same package name, and that a
> package has been uploaded to Play.

Usually the problem is mismatch of package name, but I tripple checked that it's the same in `AndroidManifest`, in `build.gradle` and in `google-services.json`, and it also matches to the app in Firebase. I've also checked app fingerprints and they match the app that is on Google Play. I've downloaded google-services.json from Firebase and compared it to what we have and it's identical. Everything matches. Also worth noting is that we see Crashlytics and Analytics data in Firebase, all working well. It's just that the explicit connection to Google Play is not working (we want it so we can also see revenue from within Firebase, and some other things).

What is wrong?

I spent hours on this but only found [1 similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949265/firebase-app-distribution-app-is-linking-to-google-play-app-not-found) on SO without answers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue. Checked all these things as well, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

To address the "No matching Play apps found" issue:

1. Ensure that if your Firebase account differs from your Google Play account, you grant the necessary permissions to your Google Play account. Specifically, provide the email associated with your Google Play account for the following service roles:

- Firebase Admin
- Firebase App Distribution Admin
- Owner

2. To assign the "Firebase Owner" role, navigate to "Users and permissions" under "Project settings". For the "Firebase App Distribution Admin" role, use the IAM settings.

I hope this guidance assists others experiencing similar challenges.

Comment: Thank you, that was the case for me - I did not notice that I used two different users. by adding the the google play user as an owner in the firebase console I was able to link the two.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally was able to resolve this! I had to upload an internal testing aab app directly into the Google Play store. So basically I went through all the play store setup, and manually uploaded the android asset and ONLY then I was able to see the "Link" on firebase to actually link the two.

Really surprised this isn't explained anywhere, but seems you need to have the app uploaded in the play store FIRST with the same package name, and then Firebase/Google Play console gives you the option to link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already have our app in the Play Store, but I am still seeing the No Matching message. I do have 5 apps on Firebase project for different environments and only 1 matches the play store prod app.

Comment: My app is also uploaded to Play Store but no option of link in firebase. My OTP is not working that's why I am doing that.